# Add query to training data using CURL

Tags: json, curl, training-data, watson-discovery, wds

In the Watson API documentation, the following is given for adding query to training data using CURL:

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d
'{
  "natural_language_query": "who is keyser soze",
  "filter": "text:criminology",
  "examples": [
    {
      "document_id": "adaf50f1-2526-4fad-b670-7d6e8a42e6e6",
      "relevance": 2
    },
    {
      "document_id": "63919442-7d5b-4cae-ab7e-56f58b1390fe",
      "cross_reference": "my_id_field:14",
      "relevance": 4
    }
  ]
}' "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/v1/environments/{environment_id}/collections/{collection_id}/training_data?version=2018-03-05"
```

However much I try or use multiple libraries, it does not seem to have the correct JSON format (even when JSON validators have confirmed).

Has anyone tried using this method to add queries?

Comment: Do you have an example error and library?

Comment: If the linebreak is before the single quote, the payload is ignored. What happens if you join the first two lines?

Comment: Why not saving the data to a file and use with `-d @data.json `?